# Safari 14 Frequency Visited... isn't

Tags: safari

After the upgrade to Safari 14 on macOS, Version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610) to be exact, the Frequently Visited list is... well, *not* my Frequently Visited. I've never seen more than one web site show up in it after the update, although I used to have about a half dozen, /., Ars and here at SO. Now it's showing me a page I visited yesterday, once, and nothing else.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I second nohillside question. However, there are two Frequently Visited settings worth of checking: is 'Frequently visited' checked in Start Page preferences and the position of Show Less / Show More toggle in right end of 'Frequently Visited' header (it appears when hovering on header)